# How do I connect an ExpressJS backend to a SvelteKit frontend?

Tags: express, sveltekit

I'm trying to create an app that uses **ExpressJS** as the backend and **SvelteKit** as the frontend. Express will be the entry point for the web server, so for example /api/ requests will be routed to ExpressJS and anything other than this will be sent to the SvelteKit frontend.

I'm using the node adaptor for SvelteKit and have found that it makes a fully contained node server in '/build/index.js' for the SvelteKit application.

However, this is where I'm stuck now and I'm not sure how to route the requests to the frontend through the Express app. Any help would be much appreciated. I'd ideally like to have this contained within one project.

Link to the node adaptor: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/adapter-node/README.md

Comment: I think I'm trying to do something similar. Can you tell me about how you setup your project? e.g. did you just install sveltejs/kit, or did you need to install sveltejs/adapter-auto as well?

Comment: im planning to make npm package, which will provide express functionality in svelte +server.ts , please ping me if ur interested, its a mid sized work, cant do alone, essentially , makes svelte as primary framework and removes the need for mounting the svelte handler...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I worked it out! These two lines solve this in the express app:

```
import { handler } from './build/handler.js';
app.use(handler);
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, please accept your own answer to mark it as solved

Comment: Question on this: This will only happen after `npm run build(vite build)`. I assume we will lose the original `npm run dev` refresh experience provided by SvelteKit. Any solution to make this more seamless?

Comment: @Luckybug sadly, not yet. We need to wait until SvelteKit provides us with a proper API to interact with the server which is not possible at all right now.

Comment: @Luckybug I wrapped nodemon in a bash script to get close to what you (and I) are wanting:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

nodemon -e svelte,js,html,json,css  \
    -w client/src \
    -w client/index.html \
    -w client/jsconfig.json \
    -w client/package.json \
    -w client/postcss.config.cjs  \
    -w client/README.md \
    -w client/tailwind.config.cjs \
    -w client/vite.config.js \
    -w server \
    -i client/node_modules \
    -i server/public/dist \
    -i server/node_modules \
    -x ./buildClientStartServer.sh $1
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer! I am in a similar situaiton, but want to understand the project structure. Are the Express/Node project and SvelteKit project in different folders? Or are they all under the same node project?

Comment: Do you mind to share the whole file. I can't get the npm run build to use my own server. It's always using the index.js instead of myownserver.js

Answer (score 2):

This is the perfect answer but sometime if you new to express and svelte, then always use app.use(handler) after express routes defined. Otherwise express routes wont work.

EX -
You might get errors like this, i posted because it might save some people time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLDTv.png

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out as it is not clear from the doc.

Comment: Do you have an example to how my own expressjs be used with the frontend?